# proftpd 1.34 and files size > 2 GB

Tags: linux, ftp

I have two local Linux (Slackware) servers. One has ProFTPD V1.34c and the other ProFTPD 1.34a.  They both have files greater than 2 GB on them. Using "get" they both (a to b and b to a) stop transferring when the file size reaches 2,147,483,647 bytes.  My understanding is that version 1.34 should handle file sizes greater than 2 GB.  Both machines are on the same local network with no firewalls between them and there is nothing that I can see in /etc/proftpd.conf on either machine that would be restrictive.  As far as I know there is also no default restriction that I have to overcome.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In cases someone else stumbles across this looking for a solution to a 
similar problem, I never did find a solution, but a work-around is using 
Core FTP on a Windows PC.  I found I could retrieve the large file from 
Linux server A to a Windows PC using Core FTP and then push it to 
Linux server B.  It would have been nice to find an actual solution to 
go directly from A to B but at least I was able to move the file.